# Visual effects are not highlighted

Tags: 10.10, unity, ubuntu-netbook, compiz

I installed Ubuntu Netbook edition on my laptop, and in **System → Preferences → Appearance**, visual effects were not highlighted, so is there anyway to enable it? Now I'm using desktop mode at login.

Comment: I think it's not possible to run Compiz in Netbook Edition, because it uses Unity with Mutter as composite desktop...

Answer (score 1):

If you want these effects, you would need to install [compiz](http://packages.ubuntu.com/compiz), but I don't know if it would work with Unity installed.

Answer (score 0):

It happens also in the desktop edition because you need to have desktop effects activated when using Unity.

So if you are using Unity you have the effects, try enabling some of them in Compiz, they will work!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the necessary (in my case the proprietary nVidia) driver installed?

AFAIK you need it to enable the Visual Effects on the desktop.